# Get the parent index of the array angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I searching and I found out that this code is what I need right now. But there is something wrong about it. When I clicked the alertme button it's alert is -1 which is wrong. When I click 1 Brick med it's alert -1 it should be 0 because the no and name is in sectionA. When I want t click 3 Frank Joemar Timbang it should alert 1 because he is in sectionB? Aney help? suggestions? TIA

```js
var stud = angular.module("stud", []);
stud.controller("StudentsController", function ($scope) {
 'use strict';
  
  
  $scope.alertMe = function (studentGroup) {
    alert($scope.students.indexOf(studentGroup));
};
    $scope.sectionA = [
      {
        no:1,
        name:'Brick Med',
      },
      {
        no:2,
        name: 'Colin Christopher',
      },
    ];
      
     $scope.sectionB = [
      {
        no:3,
        name: 'Frank Joemar Timbang',
      },
      {
        no:4,
        name: 'Curtis Zaymond',
      }
      ];
    
    $scope.students = [
      $scope.sectionA,
      $scope.sectionB
    ];

     

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="stud">
<head lang="en">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Students</title>
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="StudentsController" data-ng-init="init()">
  <div id="container">
   </div>
  <div class="container-table">
    <table border="1" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Students</td>
                <td>Alert</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
       <tbody ng-repeat="studentGroup in students">
    <tr ng-repeat="student in studentGroup">
        <td>{{student.no}} {{student.name}}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="alertMe($parent.$index)">Alert me!</button></td> 
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay so your problem is that you are using indexOf() when you want to just be using studentGroup as the index.

```
$scope.alertMe = function (studentGroup) {
     alert($scope.students[studentGroup]); // returns object object in your array
     alert($scope.students[studentGroup][0]); /// returns sectionA object1
     alert($scope.students[studentGroup][0].name); /// returns sectionA object1 name
};
```

And I fixed up your html so it is easier to read but your original stuff should still work.

```
   <tbody ng-repeat="studentGroup in students" ng-init="studentsIndex = $index">
    <tr ng-repeat="student in studentGroup">
        <td>{{student.no}} {{student.name}}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="alertMe(studentsIndex)">Alert me!</button></td> 
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

If this isn't what you want and you really want to alert the index, let me explain how indexOf works. That method will take a search parameter, and that is used to search an array for that element data. It is returning -1 right now because you give it the index and it searches for that index as the element data in index 0 and 1. Steps: Does whatever index = $scope.sectionA , Nope move on, Does whatever index = $scope.sectionB, nope move on. Done, did not find search parameter return -1.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying me about the how the index0f works. I run your code but it's alert me  [object, object],[object, object].

Comment: If you look at my entire answer you will see I gave instructions how to get the name property out of those objects. You must apply those techniques to get the proper information you want from those objects.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `indexOf`. `studentGroup` is set correctly to `0` for the first 2 rows and `1` for the next 2. If you want the section array you should use

```
$scope.alertMe = function (studentGroup) {
    alert($scope.students[studentGroup]);
};
```

Comment: I tried your code but it's alert me [object, object],[object, object].